# AngularJS - Dynamic Title with interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, coffeescript

### Problem

I am currently trying to figure out a way to dynamically change the `<title></title>` template when a `$route` changes. I've seen various solutions for doing this which involve either `$broadcast`ing a message or passing around a factory to `setTitle` or something to that effect. I would like if I could simply define this at my `$routeProvider` level but *also* allow it to be flexible enough to use a variable on the current scope of the `$route`.

### What I Have

Currently I have a somewhat working solution that uses `$interpolate` to achieve what I want; the problem is that if, for instance, the property is set after an AJAX call, the template isn't updated.

#### `routes.coffee`

```coffee
angular.module('app').config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
    .when '/',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
      controller: 'Home'
    .when '/person/:id'
      templateUrl: 'templates/person.html'
      controller: 'Person'
      title: '{{name}} ({{age}})'
]
```

#### `lwTitle.coffee`

```coffee
angular.module('app').directive 'lwTitle', ['$route', '$interpolate', ($route, $interpolate) ->
  link: (scope, el) ->
    whenRouteScopeChanges = -> $route.current?.scope
    updateTitle = (routeScope) ->
      if routeScope
        title = $route.current?.$$route.title or 'Home'
        el.html $interpolate("#{title} - My App")(routeScope)

    scope.$watch whenRouteScopeChanges, updateTitle
]
```

Again, this works; but if, for instance, the `person` and `age` attributes on `routeScope` (in the case of the `/person/:id` route) are set only after an AJAX call, I get an empty string for their values.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for? I really want to set the `<title></title>` element's template dynamically, as well as to tell it the scope of it is `routeScope` when the route changes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [resolve property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) on your route - then first your ajax call will retrieve data and then route will be populated.

> route.resolve - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

it can look like this

```
 //normal javascript
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  resolve:{
    promiseObject:  function($http){
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'})
            .then (function (data) {
              return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
             });
    }
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `resolve`. I do like this approach as often times the controller I'm going to depends on the success of the promise anyway; this way the user doesn't go to the page until that's been resolved.

Comment: I _still_ would like to know if there's a way to do what I was trying to, where I could just `$compile` the template or something into my `el` and put the `$scope` in context of the current route though.

I'll wait a bit to see if there's any way to do this, but I will likely accept this answer. Thanks again :)